# Database ORM for local database

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce

I would like to use a database in local application. During my research I found that SQLite and SCL Ce are the most appropriate for what I am trying to do. The most promoted ORM lately is Entity Framework 4 which unfortunately doesn't support these databases out of the box for desktop applications. What I am trying to achieve is to create database programmatically which ideally would be generated via "code first" or "model first" approach which later can be be manipulated via (CRUD) transaction. Should I go for Ling to SQL or maybe no ORM at all for better support?

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework 4.1 (Code First) fully supports SQL Server CE 4.  Both are available easily via [NuGet](http://nuget.org).

Comment: It is true for ASP.NET/MVC applications but not for local ones e.g. WPF. There are some workarounds out there, however if I am going to choose them I'd rather go with SQLite.